# Pandas groupby and max of string column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(6,2)),columns = list("AB"))
df["A"] = ["1111","2222","1111","1111","2222","1111"]
df["B"] = ["20010101","20010101","20010101","20010101","20010201","20010201"]
df
```

OP:

```
     A          B       
 0  1111    20010101    
 1  2222    20010101    
 2  1111    20010101    
 3  1111    20010101    
 4  2222    20010201    
 5  1111    20010201
```

I am trying to find the max transactions done by the user_id in a single day.

For example, for ID: "1111" has done 3 transactions on "200010101" and 1 transaction on "20010201" so the maximum here should be 3, while the ID: 2222 has done 1 transaction on "20010101" and 1 transaction on "20010202" so the op is 1.

Expected OP:

```
       MAX TRANS IN SINGLE DAY

1111      3
2222      1
```

Any pandas way to achieve this instead of creating groups and iterating through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find max you need `groupby`, `unstack`, `max` on index

```
In [1832]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].count().unstack().max(axis=1)
Out[1832]:
A
1111    3
2222    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `groupby` twice. First we get the count of each occurence in column `B` of each ID in column `A`. Then we groupby again and get the max value:

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['B'].count())\
                  .rename({'B':'MAX TRANS SINGLE DAY'}, axis=1)\
                  .reset_index()

df = df2.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg({'MAX TRANS SINGLE DAY':['max', 'min']})

print(df)
      A MAX TRANS SINGLE DAY    
                         max min
0  1111                    3   1
1  2222                    1   1
```

Comment: I have to both min and max. this solution requires calling the above snippet twice with ".max" and ".min". Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In your question you state, you want the `max transactions` @vikky

Comment: @vikky the minimum is always going to be 1 though? (based on how you've described the `max` criteria....) If column C was used somehow then it'd make a bit more sense but otherwise... if it's following the same criteria for the `max` then - err... it's pretty meaningless?

Comment: Yes, but when I tweak it for min. I should call the snippet twice right?

Comment: You can do `.agg` which can apply multiple aggregations on a group - but I think Erfan's answered what your question actually was @vikky :)

Comment: @JonClements not necessary right. For example a user could have done 2 transactions on "20010101" and 4 transactions on "20010201". then the minimum is 2 in this case.

Comment: @JonClements can you help me with a psuedo of the solution with multiple aggregations using "agg" function.

Comment: @vikky it's 1am and I'm already far too late to bed... the docs are fairly good though - if you look 'em up. Good luck!

Comment: I edited my question including `min`, next time ask your question in a correct way without confusing people here. Thank you.